# core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Getting this problem always when I import anything in module for using any service by injecting it in controllers

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
// import { PhotoLibrary } from '@ionic-native/photo-library/ngx';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule,
    // PhotoLibrary,
    AngularFirestore
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

in this code snippet when ever I add PhotoLibrary or AngularFirestore this give me error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at registerNgModuleType (vendor.js:68335)
at vendor.js:68353
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at registerNgModuleType (vendor.js:68349)
at new NgModuleFactory$1 (vendor.js:68496)
at Compiler_compileModuleSync__POST_R3__ (vendor.js:72488)
at Compiler_compileModuleAsync__POST_R3__ [as compileModuleAsync] (vendor.js:72501)
at MergeMapSubscriber.project (vendor.js:98784)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (vendor.js:140384)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (vendor.js:140374)
at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3904)
at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3856)
at polyfills.js:3966
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3505)
at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:72989)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3504)
at Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:3273)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:3675)
```

Comment: using .id somewhere?

Comment: can you share  your code

Comment: when you ask question please be specific and describe your error with the code. otherwise its hard to give solution. hope you understand?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having `ng-recaptcha` take a look at the [issue#177 (comment)](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/177#issuecomment-687254265), this dependency has to be upgraded from **4.2.1** (and earlier) to `Angular` **9/10** compatible such as (as of today) **5.0.0**.